# How to repeat the task using alarm Manager in Android

Tags: java, android, service

**I want to repeat the task at specific time like 9:45, 10:10**

```
    AlarmManager alarmMgr0 = 
    (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent0 = new Intent(this,schedule.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent0 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, 
    intent0, 0);
    // Intent intent0 = new Intent(this, OldEntryRemover.class);
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 32);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    //set that timer as a RTC Wakeup to alarm manager object
    alarmMgr0.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 
    pendingIntent0);
```

Comment: actually i have schedule the task one time and its working for 9:32 but i have to repeat it at multiple time.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
private AlarmManager alarmMgr;
private PendingIntent alarmIntent;
...
alarmMgr = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);

// Set the alarm to start at 8:30 a.m.
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 8);
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);

// setRepeating() lets you specify a precise custom interval--in this case,
// 20 minutes.
alarmMgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
        1000 * 60 * 20, alarmIntent);
```

References:-https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms